# av_buffersink_get_frame() return error AVERROR(EAGAIN) -11

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I convert some other format to AVFrame and call:

```
av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, frame, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF)
```

to add the frame to filter graph, it success.

When it turns to:

```
int ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, filt_frame);
```

I got an AVERROR(EAGAIN) that show there is no frame available at this point.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it again until it succeed, as error says. It's worth adding a delay between calls using some sleep function to wait like 20ms.